# How To Create Drawable Border like some top portion some bottom Portion?

Tags: xml, kotlin, android-studio, android-drawable, xml-drawable

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLDFr.png)Please Help me to create below image to draw border in drawable using redial gradient with different color.
i already try but not create border like this.
i have attached the sample image.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="30dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#FF57F2" /> <!-- border color -->
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item

        android:start="10dp"
        android:end="16dp">   <!-- adjust borders width here -->
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="30dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#FBFBFB" />  <!-- background color -->
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```